# Can this implementation of in-order traversal of a binary tree be improved?

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, inorder

I wrote a straightforward in-order-traversal function (`toList1`) for a binary tree. However, I worry about its complexity (memory / time). Is there a better way to implement it?

```hs
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
toList1 :: (Tree a) -> [a]
toList1 Empty = []
toList1 (Node x lx rx) = (toList lx) ++ [x] ++ (toList rx)
```

Comment: Your question would be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. However, here is a tip: you can make [the concatenate vanish](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/vanish/vanish.pdf) in the last equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell's append `++` performs linearly in the length of its left argument, which means that you may get *quadratic* performance if the tree *leans left*. 
One possibility would be to use [**difference list**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list).

Another one would be to define a [**Foldable**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Foldable) instance:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

instance Foldable Tree where
    foldr f z Empty = z
    foldr f z (Node a l r) = foldr f (f a (foldr f z r)) l
```

then, in-order-traversal comes out naturally:

```
toList :: Tree a -> [a]
toList = foldr (:) []
```

and

```
\> let tr = Node "root" (Node "left" Empty Empty) (Node "right" Empty Empty)
\> toList tr
["left","root","right"]
```

Comment: I am not sure if I correctly understand you. For perfect balanced tree my algorithm is linear ?