# Replacement '++' with ':' in Haskell. Error

Tags: haskell

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty 


toList :: (Tree a) -> [a]  
toList (Node v l r ) = (toList l) ++ [v] ++ (toList r)
toList Empty = []
```

As we know it is not optimal because every `++` is connected with O(n) operations for concatenation of lists. The alternative solution is to use `:` instead of `++`. But it causes error because of the fact `toList Empty = []`. So how to make optimal my solution?

Comment: `:` and `++` have different types and serve different functions. You could write `toList l ++ (v : toList r)` if you wish, but you can't use `:` for two lists.

Comment: @Mephy: correct. BTW the parens aren't necessary since both `:` and `++` are `infixr 5`.

Comment: You need to *reassociate* the `++` applications until the left operand of each is a singleton. Then you can (essentially) replace each with `:`.

Comment: [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35831388/625914) replaces `++` with `:` by defining a Foldable instance. it seems like it is literally same question as yours

Answer (score 7):

You can't do it directly, since `:` only prepends a *single element* to a list. But in both child-branches you'll usually give multiple elements. The slow recursive implementation is *needed* to get around precisely this!

So, the way to go is to use a container with a more efficient concatenation operation! Such are available in libraries, e.g. [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html). But there is one container type that you can very quickly brew up yourself:

```
newtype DList a = DList { getDList :: [a] -> [a] }

instance Monoid (DList a) where
  mempty = DList id
  mappend (DList l1) (DList l2) = DList $ l1 . l2

singletonD :: a -> DList a
singletonD x = DList (x:)
```

With this, you can do

```
toDList :: Tree a -> DList a 
toDList (Node v l r) = toDList l <> singletonD v <> toDList r
toDList Empty = mempty
```

This is an exact translation of your definition, but it won't have the same performance problem as when you concatenate ordinary lists.

Because these [difference lists](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list) are so easy to implement, it's quite common in Haskell to just do it inline without further mention:

```
toList :: (Tree a) -> [a]  
toList t = tdl t []
 where tdl (Node v l r) = toList l . (v:) . tdl r
       tdl Empty = id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put things together differently to accomplish your goal. You can't just replace `++` with `:`. Try this:

```
toList t = toListPlus t []
toListPlus :: Tree a -> [a] -> [a]
```

`toListPlus t xs` should produce `toList t ++ xs`, but implemented with recursive calls to `toListPlus`, not using `++` or `toList`. Let's work through it. The base case is easy:

```
toListPlus Empty xs = xs
```

The recursive case isn't too bad either. We want to convert the left subtree to a list, sticking other stuff on after:

```
toListPlus (Node v l r) xs =
  toListPlus l ???
```

What comes after? The root, and then the result of converting the right subtree, and then whatever gets tacked on:

```
toListPlus (Node v l r) xs =
  toListPlus l (v : toListPlus r xs)
```

This function uses an implicit stack to keep track of the remaining work. This is probably the most efficient way to do it. If you wanted, you could use a zipper-style representation to make the stack explicit.

---

How does this solution relate to the one leftaroundabout described? Well, they're actually the same. We can see that by shifting the list argument over:

```
toListPlus Empty = \xs -> xs
toListPlus (Node v l r)
  = \xs -> toListPlus l (v : toListPlus r xs)
  = toListPlus l . (v :) . toListPlus r
```